# Cannot delete onedrive folder error message: The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid

Tags: onedrive, delete-file

I have recently canceled the backup of onedrive of my desktop. The when deleting desktop between my one drive files I cannot remove it. It does not present any error messages it just does nothing. When I go deeper into the folders I find out that one folder is blocking the delete action for the desktop folder in my one drive. (I can remove it online but it can not do that on my pc). When I try to open this one folder I get the error message: The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.

I tried different solutions from other forums. Them being chkdsk /r /f (:C) as well as removing in cmd as administor: del /f constrs_1 or del constrs_1 both won't work either (constrs_1 is the folder name folder form a vivado project).

So my question is: Is there another solution to forcefully delete a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and exact same error. The chkdsk /r /f fixed it for me. Before that, I tried resetting OneDrive but that doesn't fix the issue for me.

So you may want to retry the chkdsk step again.

This below command can forcefully delete everything in the folder but it won't work if you still have this error around: "The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid."

del /S /F /Q *.*